# EF Core Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Colour.ColourGroups' of type 'ICollection<ColourGroup>'

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have the following 3 tables in a legacy database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Colour(
ColourCode char(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Colour PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ColourCode ASC
)

CREATE TABLE ColourGroup(
    ColourGroup varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_ColourGroup PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ColourGroup ASC
)

CREATE TABLE Colour_ColourGroup(
    ColourCode char(3) NOT NULL,
    ColourGroup varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Colour_ColourGroup PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ColourCode ASC,
    ColourGroup ASC
)

ALTER TABLE Colour_ColourGroup  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Colour_ColourGroup_Colour FOREIGN KEY(ColourCode)
REFERENCES Colour (ColourCode)

ALTER TABLE Colour_ColourGroup  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Colour_ColourGroup_ColourGroup FOREIGN KEY(ColourGroup)
REFERENCES ColourGroup (ColourGroup)
```

and the following EF classes to represent them in code

```cs
public class Colour
{
    public string ColourId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ColourGroup> ColourGroups { get; set; }
}
public class ColourGroup
{
    public string ColourGroupId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
}
public class ColourColourGroup
{
    public string ColourId { get; set; }
    public string ColourGroupId { get; set; }

    public Colour Colour { get; set; }
    public ColourGroup ColourGroup { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using Fluent API to link ColourColourGroup to the Colour_ColourGroup table and to specify some DB column names.

```cs
builder.Entity<Colour>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.ColourId).HasColumnType("char(3)")
          .HasColumnName("ColourCode");
    entity.Property(e => e.FinishId).HasMaxLength(3);
    entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(30);
    entity.HasKey(e => e.ColourId);
});
builder.Entity<ColourGroup>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.ColourGroupId).HasMaxLength(6)
          .HasColumnName("ColourGroup");
    entity.HasKey(e => e.ColourGroupId);
});
builder.Entity<ColourColourGroup>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Colour_ColourGroup");
    entity.Property(e => e.ColourGroupId).HasMaxLength(6)
          .HasColumnName("ColourGroup");
    entity.Property(e => e.ColourId).HasMaxLength(3)
          .HasColumnName("ColourCode");
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ColourId, e.ColourGroupId });
});
```

But I don't know how to link the 3 tables together. If it was just a one-to-many relationship between Colour and ColourGroup, I think you'd use InverseProperty (or whatever the Fluent equivalent is) on ColourGroup.Colours.

Any query that accesses these entities fail with the above error, for example:

```cs
var group = _context.ColourGroups.Where(g => g.ColourGroupId == "ALLPC").FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I tell EF that the Colour.ColourGroups and ColourGroup.Colours properties are "mapped" by the corresponding properties in ColourColourGroup?

Comment: Documentation: [Relationships - Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many). Shortly, both collections must be of type `ICollection<ColourColourGroup>`

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, that seems to work. It's a pity you can't access the foreign entity directly (Colour.ColourGroups), but I guess Colour.ColourColourGroups.ColourGroup is okay..
If you put that comment as an answer, I'll accept it.